# Coverting String to byte in Java

Tags: java, string, hex, byte

Having:

```
byte temp;
```

and a String which represents a binary number:

```
String binary = "00100100";
```

I want to convert this binary number to hex and store it in byte, so: as 00100100 binary equals 24 hex, I want to obtain:

```
temp = 24;
```

or

```
temp = 0x24;
```

Comment: `0x24` is an integer literal. It's not something you will convert a String value to.

Comment: I have done the following: `int decimal = Integer.parseInt(binary, 2); //gives 36`, `String hexadecimal = Integer.toHexString(decimal); //gives 24` but then when I do `temp = Byte.parseByte(hexadecimal,16); //it gives me 36 not 24`. I do not understand why it is converting back to decimal.

Comment: `Byte` is an integer value represented in base 10. `36` in base 10 is `24` in base 16. They are the same number.

Comment: Computers hold *values*. The textual representation is only for human consumption. You don't "convert it to hex and store it as a byte"; you simply convert the string to a byte value. If you want to print that value as text in a particular base, there are methods to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example

```
String binary = "00100100";
int value = Integer.parseInt(binary, 2);
System.out.println(value);
System.out.println("0x" + Integer.toHexString(value));
```

[`Integer.parserInt(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

> Parses the string argument as a signed integer in the radix specified by the second argument.

So it will convert the binary String value to an integer with the specified base.

You can then use the [`Integer.toHexString(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29) method to convert that value to a hex representation, appending the `0x` if you really want to.

Comment: please see my comment above. I did it the same way, but I have a problem with putting it in byte.

Comment: @sashafierce Basically, if you want a hexadecimal representation, you have to use the `toHexString` method. But on a computer, a byte you get from `parseByte(value, 16)` and a byte you get from its base 10 representation are the exact same number.